# PyQt5 converting signal code from PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm a newbie and  am having difficulty changing a line of code from PyQT4 to PyQT5, its to do with signals & slots.  I suspect its because arguments are being passed to the slot.

Original line was:

```
self.connect(self.assetView.selectionModel(), SIGNAL(("currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)")),self.assetChanged)
```

I’ve tried:

```
self.assetView.selectionModel.currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex).connect(self.assetChanged)
```

and I get: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'currentRowChanged'`

self.assetView is a QTableView and self.assetChanged has def:

```
  def assetChanged(self, index):
```

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new syntax is as follows:

```
sender.signal.connect(some_slot)
```

In your case:

```
self.assetView.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(self.assetChanged)

#   ^^^^^^^^^sender^^^^^^^^       ^^^^signal^^^^            ^^^^^^slot^^^^^^
```

and

```
def assetChanged(self, current, previous):
    print(current, previous)
```